# Unable to Load staging variables in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, package.json, staging

Below is my package.json and I am trying to load staging variables. In my root directory, I am having three environment file i.e. .env.local, .env.production, .env.staging.
But only .env.local, .env.production are being loaded.

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build-staging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging next build",
    "staging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging next start",
    "build-prod": "env-cmd -f .env.production next build",
    "prod": "env-cmd -f .env.production next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "18.15.10",
    "@types/react": "18.0.30",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.11",
    "eslint": "8.36.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.2.4",
    "next": "13.2.4",
    "next-pwa": "^5.6.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "yarn": "^1.22.19"
  }
}
```

When I am running the script "npm build-staging". It is not loading .ev.staging file. Below is the logs.

```
> env-cmd -f .env.staging next build

info  - Loaded env from /Users/nityanand/NextPOC/my-app/.env.local
info  - Loaded env from /Users/nityanand/NextPOC/my-app/.env.productioninfo  - Linting and checking validity of types  
> [PWA] Compile server
> [PWA] Compile client (static)
> [PWA] Auto register service worker with: /Users/nityanand/NextPOC/my-app/node_modules/next-pwa/register.js
> [PWA] Service worker: /Users/nityanand/NextPOC/my-app/public/sw.js
> [PWA]   url: /sw.js
> [PWA]   scope: /
> [PWA] Compile server
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Collecting page data  
info  - Generating static pages (3/3)
info  - Finalizing page optimization
```